# geth clique block gas limit

Tags: poa

I have setup new PoA network with default block gas limit to 3 billions. The network starts with configured limit. However, overtime the block gas limit reduce down to 8 millions. Is there a way to prevent geth from adjusting the block gas limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the gas limit option for geth,

For example,

`geth --miner.gastarget=3000000000 --miner.gaslimit=3000000000`